# What is the difference between render() of DjangoTemplates class and render() method found in django.shortcuts module?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to learn Django. I am creating a small applicationt to understand its basic functionalities. In views.py of a django app, some tutorials use render() from template while others use render() from django shortcuts module.

For instance, in views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def home(request):
    context = {}
    template = "app/add_item.html"
    return render(request, template,context)
```

and yet others,

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from app.models import Items # this is the model
def home(request):
    item_list = Items.objects.order_by('-item_name')
    template = loader.get_template('app/add_item.html') # could be index.html as well
    context = {
        'item_list': item_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

What is the difference between render() method of DjangoTemplates class and render() method found in django.shortcuts module? Which one should I prefer and why?

Answer (score 3):

[`django.shortcuts.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) is, as its name implies, a shortcut for returning a rendered template as a response from a view. Its use is rather limited to that context. It takes an `HttpRequest` instance as its first argument and its main purpose, per the docs, is to

> combine a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text.

Importantly, this selects a template by name. It is intended to *select* a template for rendering and returning as a response.

[`Template.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render) is part of the low-level template API and takes the single template, represented by that object, and renders it to a string.

Importantly, this takes only the template already represented by your object. It has no mechanism for discovering another template to render.

---

Generally, the shortcut version is the most useful, as quite often you want to return a rendered template as a response from your views. This is the whole reason it exists.

Comment: Thanks. But "It has no mechanism for discovering another template to render". Even for ```django.shortcuts.render```, you give explicitly the html template. Is n t it?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I mean that with the render function (`django.shortcuts.render`), it expects an argument telling it what template to render. `Template.render` will only ever render that one template. There is no argument you can pass to make it render something else. Make more sense?